# SQL Query to segregate the data

Tags: sql-server, spotfire

My data set is as follows: which Indicates the movement of transport where `T` Indicates it is moving, `F` Indicates it is `Stationary`

I want the data to classify as follows for further analysis. Need to derive the `Class` based on the column `Moving` and should be counted from `0` and when the moving value changes from `T` to `F` then again recounted from `F` from `0`. Next column `ID` is to group the Moving Set values from `0` to Increment level.

**Output:**

[image: Img]

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the DB with SQL or in Spotfire with a Calculated Column? Depending on your answer, I would adjust your tags as they are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Common Table Expression to achieve your goal:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

First, you have to order your data by the movement date, and you can use ROW_NUMBER: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Here a sample request:

```
;WITH orderedMovements AS
(
    SELECT [Date], [Moving], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM [dbo].[movements]
), completedMovements AS
(
    SELECT omo.[Date], omo.[Moving], 0 AS [Class], 0 AS [Id], omo.[RowNum] AS [RowNumBis]
    FROM orderedMovements omo
    WHERE [RowNum] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT omo.[Date], omo.[Moving], IIF(cmo.[Moving] = omo.[Moving], cmo.[Class] + 1, 0) AS [Class], IIF(cmo.[Moving] = omo.[Moving], cmo.[Id], cmo.[Id] + 1) AS [Id], omo.[RowNum]
    FROM orderedMovements omo
            JOIN completedMovements cmo ON omo.[RowNum] = cmo.[RowNumBis] + 1
)
SELECT [Date], [Moving], [Class], [Id]
FROM completedMovements
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```